# Set gravity in list item layout

Tags: android, listview, gravity

I have a problem with setting gravity of a list item layout. I have a list layout which has 2 textviews. The first one has right gravity and second one has left gravity. When I load list view I always get right gravity.

Here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/poem_verse_list_item_01"
        style="@style/TextAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/poem_verse_list_item_02"
        style="@style/TextAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my Cursor and its ViewBinder:

```
public class CustomViewBinder implements ViewBinder {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

        int getIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ClubCP.COLUMN_POSITION);
        int position = cursor.getInt(getIndex);
       // Log.i("ViewBinder position",position);




        TextView right =(TextView)view;
        int viewId = view.getId();
        switch(position){
        case 0 :
             //   Right = 0,

            if(viewId==R.id.poem_verse_list_item_02){
                view.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            }
            else if(viewId==R.id.poem_verse_list_item_01){
                view.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            }
            //left.setVisibility(left.GONE);
            //right.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
           // text.setVisibility(text.GONE);
          //  return true;
        case 1:
               //     Left = 1,
            if(viewId==R.id.poem_verse_list_item_02){
                view.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            }
            else if(viewId==R.id.poem_verse_list_item_01){
                view.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            }

            //left.setVisibility(left.GONE);
            //right.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
             // return true;
        case 2:
        case 3:

        case 4:

        case -1:

        }


        return false;
        }
}

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.poem_verse_list_item, c, 
                columns, new int[] {R.id.poem_verse_list_item_01,R.id.poem_verse_list_item_02}, 0);
```

I tested a lot but each time I get only right or left gravity for both of them... I hope some one can help me. Thanks for your time.

This is my activity including ListView layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff64512f"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
tools:context=".Read_peom" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/list_top_repeat" />

<ImageView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/list_bottom_repeat" />

<ImageView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/list_left_repeat" />

<ImageView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/list_right_repeat" />

<ImageView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/list_top_left_no_repeat" />

<ImageView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/list_top_right_no_repeat" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/list_bottom_left_no_repeat" />

<ImageView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:src="@drawable/list_bottom_right_no_repeat" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_poem_container_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_poem_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/list_top_margin"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:padding="5dp" >

</ListView>
```

Comment: i m able to see both alignment are coming correct with above layout, however                android:layout_gravity="right" &             android:layout_gravity="left" are not needed, please share your main layout also

Comment: Thanks my friend I added my activitys layout

Answer (score 2):

Remove `android:layout_gravity` from both the TextViews since `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

OR

make `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and remove `android:gravity` from both the TextViews.

ELSE

You may also try a RelativeLayout with TextViews having android:layout_width="wrap_content" and android:layout_alignParentLeft or android:layout_alignParentRight set to true accordingly.

**Edit**:
To debug the issue do the following. Create a ArrayAdapter with static data and set it as the list adapter.

```
String[] arr = {"a","b","c"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.poem_verse_list_item, R.id.poem_verse_list_item_01, arr);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Then set some value using android:text to the TextViews like this.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/poem_verse_list_item_01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="poem_verse_list_item_01" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/poem_verse_list_item_02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left" 
    android:text="poem_verse_list_item_02"/>
```

So if the problem persists then the issue is not with the view binder. I would suggest you to redesign your main layout file containing the ListView.

Comment: I tested this but still all textviews come in right side..But I want some of them with left gravity and others with right at same time

Comment: Check my other suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your help..But none of them works..I think my problem is with view binder..Can you take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Try change `android:orientation="vertical"`
 to 
`android:orientation="horizontal"`

Hope this helped you

Comment: I changed it but this time all texts are with left gravity